# Stop create_react_app from re-installing global packages

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am not sure what to do about this as every time I use `create_react_app` it does

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
```

Even though I have checked that `react, react-dom, and react-scripts` packages already exist in global install location.

How do I stop `create_react_app` from reinstalling globally installed packages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_react_app` uses `npm` and for npm packages, it should only be installed globally when it provides an executable command that you run from the shell (CLI). it's npm's way to keep all the applications packages inside the node_modules to avoid conflicts, npm is different compared by something like bundler if you used it before. so the simple answer this the right way of npm and it's not needed to be changed even if this might appear like a waste of resources